# Need to split comma separated string and loop it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a comma separated string "A, B, C, D, E" and I want to run a insert query by splitting the comma separated value and running a loop.

My Insert Query

So how do I replace the id inside the query using a loop?

```
INSERT INTO `user_d` (id, flag1) VALUES (id, false)

INSERT INTO `user_d` (id, flag1) VALUES (id, false)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Postgres? Those dreaded backticks are invalid standard SQL and won't work with Postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_to_array()` and `unnest()`:

```
insert into user_d (id, flag1)
    select trim(both from unnest(string_to_array(v.str, ','))), false
    from (values ('A, B, C, D, E')) v(str) ;
```